# ros2 humble rqt drop-down menu

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

0

I am trying to use parameter in ROS2.

In ROS1, we can use parameter generator to edit cfg file and generate drop-down menu in rqt.

[image]

But I don't know how to generate in ROS2.

I have tried parameter descriptor and yaml file but still can not make it.

Please help. Thanks.

I have tried to use parameter descriptor.

It can generate a drag bar but no drop-down menu.

I also tried to use yaml file to make parameter multiple value (in a array).

But it did not show a drop - down menu but disappear in rqt.